# mysqli_insert_id() esta retornando 0 quando usado dentro de um INSERT

Tags: php, mysqli

Toda vez que tento pegar o `id` desse primeiro `INSERT`, pelo `mysqli_insert_id()`, ele retorna `0` no segundo insert e retorna o numero correto no header abaixo, o que pode ser?

```
require_once('../connects/connection.php');
session_name(md5('inv_log'));
session_start();


$evntowner = $_SESSION['uid'];



if(isset($_POST['evntnamesu']) && isset($_FILES['bgenvtpopup'])){
    $eventname = $_POST['evntnamesu'];
    $eventtype = $_POST['evntypesu'];
    $eventaccess = $_POST['evntaccsu'];


    $imagem = $_FILES["bgenvtpopup"];
    if(empty($imagem['name'])){
        $limit = "";
    }else{
    $ext = pathinfo($imagem["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $pasta = "../eventimgs/bg2/";
    $limit =  $pasta.md5($imagem["name"].mt_rand()).".".$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($imagem["tmp_name"], $limit);
}


    $eventprice = $_POST['input-money'];

    $eventlocal = $_POST['localnamesu'];
    $eventlocaladrs = $_POST['adrslocalsu'];

    $starTimeHorValue = $_POST['startTimeHor'];
    $starTimeMinValue = $_POST['startTimeMin'];
    $endTimeHorValue = $_POST['endTimeHor'];
    $endTimeMinValue = $_POST['endTimeMin'];
    $starteventtime = $starTimeHorValue.':'.$starTimeMinValue;
    $endeventtime = $endTimeHorValue.':'.$endTimeMinValue;



    $eventday = $_POST['evntdayvlpop'];
    $eventmonth = $_POST['evntmonthvlpop'];
    $eventyear = $_POST['evntyearvlpop'];
    $evntfulldate = $eventyear.'-'.$eventmonth.'-'.$eventday;

    $eventdescr = $_POST['descriptevent'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `events` (`event_id`, `event_owner_id`, `event_name`, `event_type`, `event_access`, `event_bg2`, `event_price`, `event_local`, `event_local_adrs`, `event_time_start`, `event_time_end`, `event_day`, `event_descr`) VALUES (NULL, '$evntowner', '$eventname', '$eventtype', '$eventaccess', '$limit', '$eventprice', '$eventlocal', '$eventlocaladrs', '$starteventtime', '$endeventtime', '$evntfulldate', '$eventdescr')";
    $run = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

}
$ids = $_POST['invitedVal'];
$party_id = $last_id;
if(empty($ids)){

}else{
    $idsDivide = explode(',', $ids);
        for($i = 0;$i < count($idsDivide); $i++){
            mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO invitations (inv_id, party_id, user_id, inv_status, inv_code, inv_user_status) VALUES (null, '$party_id', '$idsDivide[$i]', '1', '0', '0')");
        }
    }
    /*Redirect by function on geteventinfos.js:469*/
```

Comment: Tem uma `}` perdida no código, o primeiro insert não dá erro?

Comment: É por causa que tem mais codigo em cima, que eu cortei pra ficar mais facil a compreensao

Comment: Faça um: `var_dump(mysqli_insert_id($connection));`

Comment: O primeiro insert está dentro de um `if`. Tem certeza de que ele está sendo executado?

Comment: sim, pois ele insere as coisas dentro do db so que vem o mysqli_insert_id retornando 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tem um `{` perdido no código ,é apenas um pedaço do código correto?

Outra coisa que você deve levar em consideração é vê se todos os dados da sua query satisfazem os requisitos da table para a inserção (verificar se não tá indo `null` e etc para algum campo).

O que eu te orientado primeiramente é fazer um `var_dump` na sua variável `$sql` e um `die()` em seguida, ai você pega essa query que ela gerou e depois tenta inserir manualmente no banco de dados para ver se o erro inicialmente não é ela em vez de ser no código, caso funcione, ai você tem que analisar novamente seu código verificando a conexão (ela pode ser perdida ou pode está com problemas com a comunicação com o server).

Caso o problema persista e continue tente separar esse pedaço apenas da sua aplicação num modulo a parte e verificar se o mesmo funciona.

As vezes o problema pode está vindo de alguma outra parte do seu código, debug o mesmo que você facilmente achará a solução e se possível poste tanto o código completo como o código de conexão para podermos analisar melhor e te dá um melhor suporte.

Comment: Blz cara, vo posta!!!

Comment: mas isso que eu to tentando fazer nao existe nehuma restricao ne??

Comment: Depende do seu usuario do banco de dados, se ele tiver restrição de fazer inserts fazendo o metodo que eu te informei de pegar a query pura e executa-la você vai descobrir logo de cara e já ficará esperto para solucionar o seu problema. Mas vamos debugando com calma e partes por partes, primeiro verificar se a sua query está correta

Comment: A primeira query ta correta!!

Comment: Beleza, você já sabe que você pode fazer inserções e que sua query está correta, a próxima parte é você ver se durante a inserção você está conseguindo se conectar com o seu banco de dados, dá um var_dump na sua conexão antes de fazer a query via php e um die() e verifica o retorno.

Comment: blzz, deixa eu ver aqui!

Comment: dei o vardump na conexao, apareceu um negocio muito grande

Comment: nao cabe aqui!!

Comment: isso seria importante? ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0)??

Comment: Coloca num gist ou algo parecido para eu analisar

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bbe5787ac3cf83ab43fed99c67932b2b

Comment: Não tem nada de errado com a sua conexão, é a forma que você está adicionando mesmo, seus drivers estão ok?

Comment: como eu checo isso man

Comment: Faz um var_dump no seu insert

Comment: Aliás, foi você que colocou -1 na minha resposta?

Comment: acha, fui eu nao

Comment: ja deu o certinho ali

Comment: Mano, retorna true no meu insert!!

Comment: Excelente, provavelmente poderia ser um problema de conexão ou algo assim é sempre bom debuga o código quando acontecer essas coisas, pois assim você consegue entender melhor que aconteceu, fico feliz que tenha encontrado a solução.

Comment: vlww mano é noizzz